# Django request session cannot read the django-session table

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-sessions

I have two simple views, one is log in and the other one is just checking the session. I added `user_id` into the `request.session` and it did create a new entry in the django_session table. But when I try to get the request session in a new request. It returns an empty one.

[image]

Comment: Django comes with an authentication system. You should use it instead of trying to write your own.

Comment: Please copy and paste code as text instead of screenshots.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Comment: I found the problem..it was with Chrome POSTMAN no longer automatically add the sessionid in the cookie. I need to do that manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django already has an authentication system, and it uses sessions by default, this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html) will guide you through it

If you want to use your own authentication backend [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#)